# Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb dll appearing in deploys

Tags: c#, .net, owin

I have a web application which is made up of web forms. Slowly we are converting it over to MVC.

Last week I did a deploy to a testing environment and everything works as expected.

This week I made some changes to some ASPX/code behind files and also some user controls. I did a publish/deploy to testing and I receive an error when I browse to the site through IIS.

The error is:

> > Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e37' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comparing the bin folder of the last good deploy, to the broken deploy, the only difference is the broken deploy has one extra file - Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll

If I remove that file the website is able to load and function correctly.

The website has many projects and references, the root project (the one I right click > publish on) does not have a reference to this Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll so it must be referenced from another project.

Is there any way to fix this error without having to delete the file from the bin folder? What is causing the error?

Also both bin folders have other Owin dll files.

```
Microsoft.Owin.dll
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll
Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll
Owin.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like one of your projects use the OWIN middleware.  It also seems like someone may have tried to update the package and possibly did not do it properly.  I would right-click on the solution and click "Manage NuGet Packages" and re-install the OWIN packages.  If that does not work its likely a binding redirect issue that needs to be resolved in the `web.config`.  You may also want to see if there are any OWIN references even being used in the project.